# Yii form submition with CActiveForm

Tags: php, forms, yii

i just need to do a registration form, i'm battling with completing this task with CActiveForm. Basically its just inserting a new db record on form submit. This is what i have,

**MyView**

```
<!--begin a form-->
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'user-registration-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
   'enableClientValidation'=>true,
   'focus'=>array($model,'firstName'),
)); ?>

<!--error handling-->
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstName'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstName'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstName'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastName'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastName'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastName'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'age'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'age'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'age'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<!--end a form-->
```

**My Controller** that renders the above view, this where i'm stuck, 
I also created a model called **User**(haven't done any code in it, default)

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   public function actionIndex()
      {
        $model = User::
        $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
     }
}
```

From my research i found there is something like, jst dnt know how to use it 
[link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

```
$post=new Post;
$post->title='sample post';
$post->content='post body content';
$post->save();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in your `actionIndex`:

```
public function actionIndex()
  {
    $model = new User;
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
       $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
       if($model->save())
         //Do any stuff here. for example redirect to created user view.
    }
    $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
 }
```

I recommend you to read the [Building a blog system with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/files/yii-blog-1.1.0.pdf) tutorial. This is very good resource for learning yii better and also learn you the most important parts of any web application.

Comment: Thnks alot @hamed, i will give ds a try n gv u a feedbak. thanks fr the pdf link aswell.